# May I resize the buffered channel's size?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I'm new to Golang, and may I resize the buffered channel like:

```
var xxx // just declaration.

...

xxx = make(chan string, mysize)   // I know `xxx := make(chan string, mysize)` work, but I don't want it.

...

xxx <- "123" // using the buffered channel.
```

Answer (score 9):

Once a channel is created, its capacity (buffer size) cannot be changed. You can only create and assign a new channel with different capacity.

Note that just declaring a variable of channel type does not create and initialize a channel, it will be its [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) which is `nil` for channel types:

```
var xxx chan int
```

Here `xxx` is a variable of `chan int`, but it's not yet initialized, you cannot send any values on it. You have to create one with the builtin [`make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make) function, e.g.:

```
var xxx chan int = make(chan int, 10)
```

Or simply:

```
var xxx = make(chan int, 10)
```

Its capactiy will be `10` and it cannot be changed. You can however assign a new channel value to it, e.g.:

```
xxx = make(chan int, 20)
```

But know that if multiple goroutines access and use the `xxx` variable, the above operation may cause a data race, and changing the value of `xxx` should be synchronized with other goroutines that read it.

Also note that if goroutines do not access `xxx` but the channel is "passed" to them, then assigning a new channel value to `xxx` will not affect them, those goroutines will not know about the new channel and will continue to use the old, passed channel.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the Go language does not support resizing channels?